# Why an array of class object is getting returned with the prefix ArrayOf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a web service of which I am generating a wsdl.

It has classes and functions.

```
    public DT_PM[] EndSI_PM(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
        object[] results = this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
        return ((DT_PM[])(results[0]));
    }
```

But the wsdl create it as

```
ArrayOfDT_PM
```

and

```
<s:element name="SI_PM" type="tns:ArrayOfDT_PM"/>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfDT_PM">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DT_PM" nillable="true">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="ST" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is intended to make wsdl definition language independent. WCF service may be consumed by clients written in different programming languages. Arays may be represented with different data structures. Even in .net you can consume this data as array or as list.
To support it, arrays are defined in WSDL schema as `complexType` named `ArrayOfXXX`. Client code generator should be able to consume this and convert to correct type definition.

Update after additional questions:
According to the WSDL spec array types should be named as `ArrayOfXXX`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl.html#_types .

If you'll check the WSDL further you will see that `ArrayOfDT_PM` is defined as `sequence` of `DT_PM` elements with `unbounded` count of max occurencies.
It means that when the client code will be generated it will treat this `ArrayOfDT_PM` as a list/array of `DT_PM` elements. Which is desired result.

Comment: Yeah but if use it and send parameter using this then it might mismatch the parameters while sending hence sending null to the webservice.

Comment: The names should be identical.

Comment: Type is ok but the only thing I am concerned about is the names of the object since they are appended with Arrayof which might cause names mismatch while sending.